# Pages app in trash

Tags: pages, trash

Having tried to create and then delete a folder in Pages I now find that if I try to open Pages from the dock I get a message: "You can’t open the application “Pages” because it is in the Trash. To open this application, move it from the Trash."
However I don't see it listed in trash. I can still open Pages from the launchpad. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close Pages (quit)
2. Remove the Pages shortcut from the dock
3. Open Pages from the launchpad or from Spotlight
4. Once Pages opens, click on the dock icon and choose options, then keep in dock.